# How can I remove text after a comma from a description field of Get-ADComputer?

Tags: powershell

I want to delete everything after the comma in the description field, so Text2 and Text3. Does anyone know how I can do this? I have heard something about regex but I don't know how to use it in this case.

```
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-(1))
$Result = Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time} -Properties * | Select-Object Name,Description, @{N='LastLogonTimeStamp'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimeStamp)}}
$Result | Format-Table 

Name          Description                        LastLogonTimeStamp
----          -----------                        ------------------
SRV-TEST      Text1, Text2, Text3                10-1-2019 09:45:00
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific errors are you getting?

Comment: You might find the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6) operator of interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggestion of using -split in the comments this will return the 1st string in the array after splitting by ",".

```
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-(1))
$Result = Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time} -Properties * | Select-Object Name, @{N='Description'; E={($_.Description -split ",")[0]}}, @{N='LastLogonTimeStamp'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimeStamp)}}
$Result | Format-Table
```

Comment: Why you make a massive from string and than get a 1st element from massive? Its not the best way to use memory and CPU. You take 2 actions instead of 1, and use 3 times more memory as rely needed. I understand that in one command is not so great, but if TS have an 10 000+ PC in AD - it will be slow. So why most programs is too slow on our PC's :-)

Comment: Oh, take my worlds back! O_o I tested it on my AD with  ~10 000  PC objects. And recive some interesting thing: 

 Measure-Command -Expression { with SPLIT} takes TotalSeconds      : 73,5386477
AND Measure-Command -Expression { REPLACE} takes TotalMilliseconds : 73376,0549

So 2 actions take same time as a regExp.

Comment: And actions: $time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-(1))
$Result = Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time} -Properties * | Select-Object Name,Description,LastLogonTimeStamp   TAKES TotalSeconds      : 63,8330494.    SO about 10 sec is used to transform data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-(1))
$Result = Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time} -Properties * | Select-Object Name, @{N='Description'; E={$_.Description -replace ',.*$','' }}, @{N='LastLogonTimeStamp'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimeStamp)}} 
$Result | Format-Table
```

For me it returns:

```
Name          Description                        LastLogonTimeStamp
----          -----------                        ------------------
SRV-TEST      Text1                              10-1-2019 09:45:00
```

Comment: yes it's working, this is the solution I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Please mark my post as Answer, if its helpful.  Have a nice day!